# Remove sub directory and file extension

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

If I have site.com/page/about.php

How can I remove the sub directory and file extension?

Example: site.com/about

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this in your .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^about(\/?)$ /page/about.php [NC,L]
```

Create your .htaccess in your root folder.

Comment: You have other rules in your .htaccess file or httpd.conf?

Comment: mod_rewrite is enable? AllowOverride is set to All

Comment: What is your VirtualHost config in our httpd.conf?

Comment: according to my hosting company, I do not have access to the file but mod_rewrite is enabled by default

Comment: here's what I found: http://help.justhost.com/questions/177/How+do+I+prevent+WordPress+from+overloading+my+shared+server%3F - I updated my answer. can you try now?

Comment: I'm not sure how that is relevant to my question. This is not on Wordpress. I have mod_rewrite enabled.

Comment: I will need more information then. Can you create a file that have phpinfo() in it and check in the apache/Loaded Modules section if you see mod_rewrite? Where did you create your .htaccess file?

Comment: the .htaccess file is in the page folder

Comment: That is your problem, move the .htaccess to the ROOT of your website