# How to remove sub directory and .php extension from all urls in an includes folder?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've searched for 'how to remove subdirectory from url' a lot and most of the answers are fairly nuanced and therefore can't be applied to my scenario.

This is the closest I can get to a succinct answer:

[Remove sub directory and file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375235/remove-sub-directory-and-file-extension)

Which has the question:

> If I have site.com/page/about.php
>
> How can I remove the sub directory and file extension?
>
> Example: site.com/about

And provides the answer:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^about(\/?)$ /page/about.php [NC,L]
```

My scenario and desired outcome is very similar, I have all my 'pages' in an includes folder eg:

```
site.com/includes/home.php
site.com/includes/about.php
site.com/includes/page3.php
```

I want these files (and any files that exists in the includes folder) to be accessible at URL's like:

```
site.com/home
site.com/about
site.com/page3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the solution:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Remove sub directory from URL
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ includes/$1.php

# Remove file extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Yes, that is what is in my .htaccess now.  If I go to any URL of the format `site.com/page1` and that page is in the includes folder as `page1.php` then the required page will load.  If the page is not in the includes folder, then there will be a 404.